# what does path mean in PathDashPathEffect constructor

Tags: android, path, styles

I am working with Android PathEffect and I found a good example for that, but when I arrived to PathDashPathEffect constructor

```
   PathDashPathEffect(Path shape, float advance, float phase, PathDashPathEffect.Style style)
```

I don't know what does these parameters mean, especially **Path shap** in the documentation it said **The path to stamp along**, and in my example I have this path :

```
Path p = new Path();
 p.moveTo(-6, 4);
 p.lineTo(6,4);
 p.lineTo(6,3);
 p.lineTo(-6, 3);
 p.close();
 p.moveTo(-6, -4);
 p.lineTo(6,-4);
 p.lineTo(6,-3);
 p.lineTo(-6, -3);
```

I don't know why it closes the path after that it continues drawing it,

can you explain it to me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the `shape` witch will be repeated to draw your `shape`

you can draw any shape you want, `lines`, `polylines`, `polygones`, and your path to draw is a string of small shapes that you pass in parameter to `PathDashPathEffect`

Answer (score 0):

It just draw a shape that will be repeated during all the drown path,

Here we want that the shap is two parallel lines,

and these coordinates can be from any reference, here from (0,0) and draw these two lines.